# Is it possible to make DDE calls to Adobe Reader in Java?

Tags: java, adobe, pdfbox, dde

I look for if it is possible to make DDE calls from java program to adobe reader to print PDF document.

I tried with PDFBox. This is my code

```
PDDocument doc =  PDDocument.load("D:/mes_documents/rapport.pdf");
doc.silentPrint();
```

the problem that it asks for the location of the registration of pdf. how can I make it autosave?

Comment: @close voters: how is this too broad?

Comment: I need to print a document pdf from java program, so I search if it is possible to call adobe reader with DDE message or other library that can be an interface between java and adobe reader

Comment: The real question would be "how do I make DDE calls from java".